# Change from relative to fixed position without moving element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to "elevate" a previously relatively positioned `<div>` so that I can control its position absolutely. The div is positioned using the bootstrap grid.

To this end I want to change the style from "relative" to "fixed", but without (initially) moving the `<div>`.

I tried to find ways of getting to the absolute left property of the relative element, allowing me to simply set it when changing to the fixed position, but there doesn't seem? to be a proper way to do this (and it feels a bit hacky).

Comment: No, that's the way to maintain the position while transforming from relative to fixed.

Comment: When you want change from relative to fixed? On scroll?

Comment: @drKey I want to change on click (to later be able to animate)

Comment: @mohamedrias, I feel that it should be a way to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work; do you have a working example somewhere? If so, add it as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: I've added it as an answer now @VonLion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)** to get the coordinates of the element relative to the viewport.

In this Snippet, click a list item to freeze it in place:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var el= e.target;
  if(el.tagName==='SPAN') {
    var br= el.getBoundingClientRect();
    el.style.position= 'fixed';
    el.style.left= br.left+'px';
    el.style.top = br.top +'px';
  }
});
```

```css
body {font: 40px verdana;}
span {position: relative;  color: white; cursor: pointer}
#A {background: #036;}
#B {background: #630;}
#C {background: #063;}
#D {background: #603;}
#E {background: #360;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="A">Alpha  </span>
  <li><span id="B">Bravo  </span>
  <li><span id="C">Charlie</span>
  <li><span id="D">Delta  </span>
  <li><span id="E">Echo   </span>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample for you as you asked in comment:

I'm getting the `offset` top and left position of the element at first.

Then setting it using `.css()` Jquery API.

```js
$(function() {
  var $tobechanged = $("#tobechanged").offset();
  $("#tobechanged").css({
      top : $tobechanged.top+"px",
      left: $tobechanged.left+"px",
      position: "fixed"
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 30000px;
}

#relative {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#tobechanged {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="relative">
  
</div>
<div id="tobechanged">
  
</div>
```

Using pure JS:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var $tobechanged = document.querySelector("#tobechanged"),
  $tobechangedOffset = $tobechanged.getBoundingClientRect();
  $tobechanged.style.top = $tobechangedOffset.top+"px";
  $tobechanged.style.left = $tobechangedOffset.left+"px";
  $tobechanged.style.position = "fixed";
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 30000px;
}

#relative {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#tobechanged {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="relative">
  
</div>
<div id="tobechanged">
  
</div>
```